# Android - Viewing a specific child per group in ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, android-view, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

Is there a way to view a specific child within a group in ExpandableListView such as say, the third child **layout** for the first group without displaying the child layouts in order within a group? My situation is super complicated compared to the other SO posts I came across such that my app has a SQLite database that allows a user to add as much data (group) as they want with modifiable data (child) in each group consisting of EditTexts, so it's essential that the correct child layout gets viewed in order for the correct data to get set as EditTexts for new sessions. However, as shown in the **sample** code snippets below, the problem is that after setting getChildrenCount() to return 1 in order to view a **specific** child, the first childPosition, or 0, is always used as the index to view the first child layout via getChildView() when I want to view a specific child layout for a certain group:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ExpandableListView expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
        List<String> groupHeadersList = new ArrayList<>();
        groupHeadersList.add("Header #1");
        groupHeadersList.add("Header #2");
        groupHeadersList.add("Header #3");
        List<String> childList = new ArrayList<>();
        childList.add("Child #1");
        childList.add("Child #2");
        childList.add("Child #3");
        MyExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(this,
                groupHeadersList, childList);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
    }
}
```

ExpandableListAdapter:

```
public class MyExpandableListAdapter implements ExpandableListAdapter {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = MyExpandableListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context context;
    private List<String> groupHeadersList, childList;

    public MyExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> groupHeadersList,
                                 List<String> childList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.groupHeadersList = groupHeadersList;
        this.childList = childList;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {}

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {}

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groupHeadersList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPos) {
        return 1; // One at most in order to view a specific child
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPos) {
        return groupHeadersList.get(groupPos);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPos, int childPos) {
        return 0;

        // return childList.get(groupPos); // OBVIOUS SOLUTION, BUT I WANT TO VIEW A CERTAIN CHILD LAYOUT INSTEAD
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPos) {
        return groupPos;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPos, int childPos) {
        return childPos;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
                             ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_group, parent, false);
        }

        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        TextView headerTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        headerTextView.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPos, int childPos, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
                             ViewGroup parent) {

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "groupPos is: " + groupPos);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "childPos is: " + childPos); // KEEPS RETURNING 0, THE FIRST CHILD AFTER RETURNING 1 FROM getChildrenCount()

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        String childTitle = (String) getChild(groupPos, childPos);
        TextView childTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        childTextView.setText(childTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPos, int childPos) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {}

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {}

    @Override
    public long getCombinedChildId(long groupId, long childId) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getCombinedGroupId(long groupId) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

... and the inflated layouts, list_group and list_item, are simply TextViews. As shown above, in the snippets, I'm aware that there's a solution to **this sample**, but I was wondering how to reference a specific child layout for a certain group for the sake of my other project.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if ViewGroup's getChildAt(int index) method would be helpful here or not...

Answer (score 0):

Here you are inflating the convertView with R.layout.list_item, which is a list view
You need to use another layout with only one text view

```
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPos, int childPos, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
                             ViewGroup parent) {

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "groupPos is: " + groupPos);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "childPos is: " + childPos); // KEEPS RETURNING 0, THE FIRST CHILD AFTER RETURNING 1 FROM getChildrenCount()

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.third_list_item, parent, false);
        }

        String childTitle = (String) getChild(groupPos, 2);
        TextView childTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        childTextView.setText(childTitle);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Something like this, should work. 
Just keep in mind the layout you are inflating with and get the required child using getChild() menthod and proceed accordingly